# What's the difference between these two ways to code in vb .Net

Tags: vb.net

I have this code

```
    Dim oCliente As New Net.WebClient()
    Dim bHTML As Byte() = oCliente.DownloadData(Me.tbURL.Text)
    Dim oUTF8 As New UTF8Encoding()
    Me.tbShowArea.Text = oUTF8.GetString(bHTML)
```

and this one

```
Me.tbShowArea.Text = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(New Net.WebClient().DownloadData(Me.tbURL.Text))
```

They both do the same thing. What I want to know is, what are the pros and the cons of using either?

Comment: 1) The first option would give you the ability to debug line by line, the second would not allow that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the only difference is that the second one is chaining the functions so each one is getting the result of the previous one processing it and passing it to the next one, while the in first one each function is assigning the result to a variable.

There is no real difference in your code, but in other scenarios you may need to do more processing on the same result, in which case you use the variable. Let's say you want the `WebClient` to do more than one thing. Using the first, you can do something like:

```
Dim oCliente As New Net.WebClient()
Dim bHTML As Byte() = oCliente.DownloadData(Me.tbURL.Text)
Dim oUTF8 As New UTF8Encoding()
Me.tbShowArea.Text = oUTF8.GetString(bHTML)

bHTML = oCliente.DownloadData(Me.tbURL2.Text)
Me.tbShowArea2.Text = oUTF8.GetString(bHTML)
```

As you can see, we reused the variables to do the additional task. You cannot do that in the second way, you will have to repeat the whole thing:

```
Me.tbShowArea.Text = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(New Net.WebClient().DownloadData(Me.tbURL.Text))

Me.tbShowArea2.Text = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(New Net.WebClient().DownloadData(Me.tbURL2.Text))
```

Now imagine that you have to put this in a loop for example. You can only do that with the first way.

Answer (score 2):

If your looking for one line commands then go with a function that returns that value, but leaves the ability for debugging with development.

Function:

```
Private Function GetOnlineData(url As String) As String
  Dim oCliente As New Net.WebClient()
  Dim bHTML As Byte() = oCliente.DownloadData(url)
  Dim oUTF8 As New UTF8Encoding()
  Return oUTF8.GetString(bHTML)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Me.tbShowArea.Text = GetOnlineData(Me.tbURL.Text)
```

Answer (score 2):

A very important aspect missing in both sets of code is the fact that `WebClient` implements `IDisposable` so it must be disposed of after use by calling `.Dispose()`. This is to prevent memory leaks from resources that do not get de-allocated. Remember the garbage collector does **not** call `.Dispose()` for you. You **must** explicitly call it in your code.

The first block of code can be written as:

```
Dim oCliente As New Net.WebClient()
Dim bHTML As Byte() = oCliente.DownloadData(Me.tbURL.Text)
Dim oUTF8 As New UTF8Encoding()
Me.tbShowArea.Text = oUTF8.GetString(bHTML)
oCliente.Dispose()
```

Or, even better, using a `Using` as:

```
Using oCliente As New Net.WebClient()
    Dim bHTML As Byte() = oCliente.DownloadData("Me.tbURL.Text")
    Dim oUTF8 As New UTF8Encoding()
    Dim Me_tbShowArea_Text = oUTF8.GetString(bHTML)
End Using
```

The second block of code is **unable to be written to be able to call `.Dispose()`** so it should be avoided.

Comment: +1, really I consider this should be the accepted answer, I was beginning to think that no one would mention the most important thing. Take care about the usage of disposable instances using the methodology explained in this answer to avoid producing memory/resource consumption that will not be released/garbage-collected.

Answer (score 0):

There is no advantage in using the second apart from maybe barely reduce project size and/or make a part if the code which you know you won't touch again more compact.

That's it.

As for cons it makes debugging and tweaking far more difficult than it should be.